Enable CSP only for some path
I have a CSP policy implemented, currently without any <host-source>, so it applies for the whole host myhost.com.
Now I have a path myhost.com/somepath which I want to exclude from the CSP policy. I understand, I cannot explicitly exclude a path in the <host-source> directive. I can only specify a path, to which the policy applies.
So, is it at all possible to

enable a policy for myhost.com and
disable the same policy for myhost.com/somepath

And if so, how?
I´m using Apache Webserver Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat) and my CSP header is set within the Apache virtual host configuration:
Header set Content-Security-Policy "\
  ...
  style-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e'; \
  script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e' "

Thanks,
Lars

Only the wildcard * exists, but that is for "positive" matches only. Can you explain what exactly prompts this requirement? (Maybe there are alternative ways to solve it.)

@CBroe: Some sub-functionality of the website/application (the one in myhost.com/somepath) cannot be changed to be compatible with the CSP policy.

<host-source> specifies where external resources can be loaded from. But your question appears not to actually be about that - but that for one specific page within your application, myhost.com/somepath, you do not want to apply any CSP at all? Then it would be a matter of not sending those CSP headers, when the requested URL path is /somepath.

Okay, maybe a different question but a similar problem.
How do I apply a CSP policy for myhost.com but not for myhost.com/somepath?

Depends on how you are applying it to begin with ... Did you do it on the web server level (which server, and how), or on the application level, or ...?

I added some technical information.
But after some experimenting I assume I´m trying to use CSP in a way it is not intended.

Wrapping this into an <If> conditional should help. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples - something like <If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ ^/somepath/">...</If>

Thanks to @CBroe for the hint!
To enable CSP for the whole website / application except URI with "/somepath/" in it, this worked for me:
    <If "%{THE_REQUEST} !~ m# .*\/somepath\/.*#i">
      Header set Content-Security-Policy "\
        style-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e'; \
        script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e' "
    </If>

